Why does rss2json API for medium has a limit on response?
I'm using below API for my portfolio, which I expected will return all my blogs
GET api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@username
This API only return 5 blogs, but I want all my blogs, is there anyway we can do so. Any reason for this limitation?
